# Настройка сервера Apache2 (два виртуальных хоста на одном IP)

Tags: apache, администрирование, маршрутизатор

В общем. Ситуация следующая. Есть сервер который сидит в домашней локальной сети (192.х.х.х). На нем установлен апач. Наружу выведен только 80 порт. Внешний адрес В.В.В.В, также к машине можно достучаться по адресу локальной подсети 10.Л.Л.Л.

И есть отдельный DNS сервер, где стоит редирект на внешний адрес В.В.В.В. с имен q.site.com и w.site.com

Дак вот, можно ли сделать так, что бы запросы с этих адресов обрабатывались как разные виртуальные хосты в апаче.

И еще такой вопрос. Может ли апач узнать, с какого адреса зашел пользователь, если сам запрос до него шел через пару маршрутизаторов.

Answer (score 3):

Документация [апача](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/name-based.html) говорит как это сделать.
А [здесь](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/vhosts/examples.html) есть примеры.

Например:

```
Listen 80

NameVirtualHost 10.0.0.3:80

<VirtualHost 10.0.0.3:80>
ServerName  q.site.com
DocumentRoot /www/domain-80
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost 10.0.0.3:80>
ServerName q.site.com
DocumentRoot /www/otherdomain-80
</VirtualHost>
```

> И еще такой вопрос. Может ли апач
> узнать, с какого адреса зашел
> пользователь, если сам запрос до него
> шел через пару маршрутизаторов.

Да.

Comment: Дело в том, что подобные настройки не работают ..

Answer (score 1):

```
# portas.cfg

    NameVirtualHost *:80
    ServerName example.ru # Без этой стоки выдает ошибку
    Listen 80
    # ...

# httpd.conf

    # пустой ...

# apache2.conf

    # ...

# sites-available/default

    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName test.example.ru # Можно не писать, все равно обращение по ип будет приходить сюда.

        DocumentRoot /var/www
        <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
        </Directory>

        <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
        </Directory>

        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
        </Directory>
        ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log

        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit, alert, emerg.
        LogLevel warn

        CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access.log combined
    </VirtualHost>

# sites-available/stribog

    <VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin stribog@example.ru
        ServerName stribog.example.ru

        DocumentRoot /home/stribog
        <Directory />
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
        </Directory>

        ErrorLog /home/stribog/error.log
        # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit, alert, emerg.
        LogLevel debug
        CustomLog /home/stribog/access.log combined

    </VirtualHost>
```

Итак. Что у нас получилось? При любом обращении к нашему хосту, будут задействованы конфиги из default. За исключением адреса stribog.examlpe.com, при обращении к нему будут задействованы конфиги stribog.

Как ни странно, но в интернете не нашел нормальной инструкции. Подбирал конфиги методом проб и ошибок. Фактически дописывал строчку ... перезагружал апач ... видел ошибку ... наугад дописывал ... перезагружал ...

Да, главное не забывайте включить виртуальные хосты.

```
a2ensite stribog
```

Comment: Сам одобрить свой ответ не могу =(

Comment: Нужно подождать два дня, и появится галочка для принятия своего ответа.

Answer (score 0):

NameVirtualHost 10.0.0.3:80

```
<VirtualHost 10.0.0.3:80>

 ServerName  q.site.com

 DocumentRoot /www/domain-80

 </VirtualHost>

 <VirtualHost 10.0.0.3:80>

 ServerName w.site.com

 DocumentRoot /www/otherdomain-80

 </VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Apache: Добавление виртуальных хостов](http://sgu.kz/viewtopic.php?f=30&t=1573)