# Как указать корневую директорию сайта в .htaccess?

Tags: php, файлы, .htaccess, редирект, php.ini

делаю сайт с превью для демонстрации... Нужно, чтоб я мог создать папку, в нее положить отдельный .htaccess и указать в нем, что все файлы внутри будут ссылаться только на эту папку. Тоесть, когда я указываю картинку как /.../image.jpg, то картинка будет считать корневую директорию именно эту и абсолютный путь будет отталкиваться от нее. Перерыл уже все, советчики помогают только с вопросом по типу "как изменить директорию", а сами показывают как указать корневым файлом index.php в другой папке и не более... 
Мб поможете советом или хотяб правильным описанием моей хотелки, спасибо.

Comment: проще сделать виртуальный хост. и выглядеть будет приличнее, и извращаться не надо будет

Comment: И как сделать "виртуальный хост"? Я не до конца понимаю о чем идет речь

Comment: это базовая настройка веб-сервера. один сервер может обслуживать миллион сайтов. просто в кофиге пишется что это сервер лежит в этой папке, другой - в этой. ну и назначить этому серверу свой субдомен

Comment: 2 секунды гугления https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/24080/%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0-apache2-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BC-ip

Comment: зы: если используете openserver какой-нить, то все это делается через GUI настройки. зы2: не используйте  относительные пути `/../img`. ни к чему хорошему это не приводит.

Comment: Это все делается не на локальном хосте(я не разу не упомянул локаль, и почему вы так за нее зацепились я не знаю)! Все уже на сервере, и нужно настроить, чтобы у каждого пользователя можно было загружать папку с проектом и она работала в отдельной папке